# How do I stop recursive renders of a AccordionBody component inside a Accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, performance, jsx

I got an `<Accordion/>` component that can hold multiple `<AccordionItem/>` components. I prepared a [codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-shape-bc32x).

The problem currently is that on the initial render, all the `<AccordionItem/>` components are rendered (check the console logs in the codesandbox example). So depending on the size of the array the `<Accordion/>` component uses to render all the items, this means a lot of initial renders. Also, everytime a `<AccordionItem/>` is openend, **all the items inside the `<Accordion/>` are re-rendered again**. For performance sake, this might not be an issue with just a few items. However, in my application, this can be 10 `<AccordionItem/>` components **that have a nested accordion themselves** that are constantly getting rerendered everytime a user opens one. So this can mean that everytime a user opens an item, 50 re-renders happen or so.

I've already tried a bunch of things to eliminate this. For instance, the accordion relies on a `active` Boolean. So only rendering the body of the accordion when this `active` boolean is true eliminates the problem, like so:

```
<div className="answer">{active && <AccordionBody />}</div>
```

**However**, the dropdown animation stops working and the body is not opened completely. What can I do to only render the clicked on `<AccordionItem/>` and its body while maintaining the nice dropdown animation?

Comment: "So this can mean that everytime a user opens an item, 50 re-renders happen or so." Why is it a problem?

Comment: I don't see any console logs in your codesandbox. Code there seems to run without issue. Can you edit the sandbox to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese. I updated the codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-shape-bc32x). Sorry, I was in quite the hurry this morning. Maybe it isn't even a problem if all the componenets get rendered everytime an item is openend. It just seems a little recursive.

Comment: @DennisVash Well, I don't know if it is a problem. Maybe it slows down my app tremendously, maybe not. Anyway, it just seems unnecessary and as something that can be prevented. I just don't know how at the moment. I am not that experienced with React yet, so if you say I shouldn't worry too much about it, than that's fine aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you should let React rerender when it needs to rerender.

You are incorrectly console logging in the function body of `AccordionBody` component as an unintentional side-effect, however, even after moving the console logs into a `useEffect` (*recall that `useEffect` hook is called once per render*) the `AccordionBody` is still rerendered again as part of the `Accordion` component rerendering the `faqs` array when state updates.

React components rerender when either state or props update, or when their parent component rerenders. When a component rerenders it necessarily rerenders its entire component subtree (i.e. its children).

These additional rerenders are generally inexpensive and not necessarily an issue alone. It really depends on what each component being rerendered does when it's rerendered. ***Don't prematurely optimize!***

Tools that you can use to help performance, if there is an issue, is to memoize props, i.e. using `useMemo` or `useCallback` to provide stable prop references.

You can also memoize components as well with the [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) Higher Order Component. Given the component renders the same result from the same props, you can memoize the rendered result. In your example codesandbox this eliminates the duplicate rerenders.

AccordionBody

```
import React, { memo, useEffect } from "react";

function AccordionBody() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("AccordionBody rendered"); // <-- log once per render
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>All of the AccordionBody's are rendered</div>
      <div>So everytime an accordion item is openend</div>
      <div>The AccordionBody component gets rendered 3 times</div>
      <div>1 for every faq in the faqs array</div>
      <div>How will this impact performance in a large array?</div>
      <div>
        How do I stop these recursive re-renders, while maintaining the
        animation?
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(AccordionBody); // <-- memoize render result
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-stop-recursive-renders-of-a-accordionbody-component-inside-a-accordion]

***Note:** Don't prematurely optimize, but only look to optimize when you find a rendering or performance issue. This will typically be on a case-by-case basis.*